# Swagger UI issue with Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

Getting this error:

500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/v3/api-docs/my-service" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required attribute 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.ServerWebExchangeUtils.gateway.observation' is missing

while trying to access API docs from Swagger UI.

I'm using the following:

```
implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.0.2"

implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api:2.0.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot 3.0 have some known issues with swagger ui

in your dependencies change the spring boot version to 2.5.7

Refresh you import and it should work